# Mod Rewrite RegEx To Match Only If Previous Subset Matched

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, lookbehind

I am trying to make what I think is a simple regex for use with mod_rewrite.

I've tried various expressions, many of which I thought were promising, but all of which  ultimately failed for one reason or another. They all also seem to fail once I add start/end string delimiters.

For example, `^user/(\d{1,10})(?=/)$` was one I tried, but among other things, it seems to group the trailing slash, and I only want to group the digits. I think I need to use a positive lookbehind, but I'm having difficulty because it's looking behind at a group.

What I am trying to match is strings that 1) begin with "user/" and 2) possibly end with `(\d{1,10})/` (1 to 10 digits followed by a single slash)

Should Match:

```
user/
user/123/
user/1234567890/
```

Should not match:

```
user
user//
user/-4/
user/35.5/
user/123
user/123//
user/123/5/
user/12345678901/
```

**Edit**: Sorry about the formatting; I do not understand how to format anything via this markdown. Those examples are preceded by 4 spaces which I thought should make a code block, but obviously I thought wrong.

Comment: Re. formatting, don't forget an empty line between the code and the non-code. I added that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^user/(?:([0-9]{1,10})/)?$` should work just fine.

Comment: Didn't know you could capture inside a non-capture (which I think is what's going on there)... anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This: `^user(?=/)(/\d{1,10})?/$` Edit: if you want to group digits, `^user(?=/)(?:/(\d{1,10}))?/$`